# PHP AMAZON API GATEWAY : The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to get response from website content.geappliances.io using AWS API Gateway but always get error :

> {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/search/b2b/results\n\ncontent-type:\nhost:content.geappliances.io\nx-amz-date:20170401T041050Z\n\ncontent-type;host;x-amz-date\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20170401T041050Z\n20170401/us-east-1/execute-api/aws4_request\na8aec6a82c0f9a2471bd17faa5f2ce5cd810a16f129fca9b04347ceed54fdc61'\n"}

please somebody help me, what's wrong with my code. Here's the code :

```
function signRequest(){

    $method ='GET';
    $uri = '/search/b2b/results?N=0&Ntk=SKU&Ntt=GTX33EASKWW';

    $access_key         = 'my-access-key';
    $secretKey          = 'my-secret-key';
    $region             = 'us-east-1';
    $kService           = 'execute-api';
    $service            = 'execute-api';

    $options = array(); 
    $headers = array();
    $host    = "content.geappliances.io";
    $alg = 'sha256';

    $date = new DateTime( 'UTC' );

    $dd = $date->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' );

    $amzdate2 = new DateTime( 'UTC' );
    $amzdate2 = $amzdate2->format( 'Ymd' );
    $amzdate = $dd;

    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';

    $requestPayload = "UNSIGNED_PAYLOAD";
    $hashedPayload = hash($alg, $requestPayload);

    $canonical_uri = $uri;
    $canonical_querystring = '';

    $canonical_headers = "content-type:"."application/json"."\n"."host:".$host."\n"."x-amz-date:".$amzdate."\n";
    $signed_headers = 'content-type;host;x-amz-date';
    $canonical_request = "".$method."\n".$canonical_uri."\n".$canonical_querystring."\n".$canonical_headers."\n".$signed_headers."\n".$hashedPayload;

    $credential_scope = $amzdate2 . '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/' . 'aws4_request';
    $string_to_sign  = "".$algorithm."\n".$amzdate ."\n".$credential_scope."\n".hash('sha256', $canonical_request)."";

    $kSecret = 'AWS4' . $secretKey;
    $kDate = hash_hmac( $alg, $amzdate2, $kSecret, true );
    $kRegion = hash_hmac( $alg, $region, $kDate, true );
    $kService = hash_hmac( $alg, $service, $kRegion, true );
    $kSigning = hash_hmac( $alg, 'aws4_request', $kService, true );     
    $signature = hash_hmac( $alg, $string_to_sign, $kSigning ); 
    $authorization_header = $algorithm . ' ' . 'Credential=' . $access_key . '/' . $credential_scope . ', ' .  'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers . ', ' . 'Signature=' . $signature;

    $headers = array(
                'content-typeapplication/json', 
                "cache-control: no-cache",
                "host: content.geappliances.io",
                'x-amz-date: '.$amzdate.'', 
                'Authorization: '.$authorization_header.''
            );
    return $headers;

}

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://content.geappliances.io/search/b2b/results?N=0&Ntk=SKU&Ntt=GTX33EASKWW",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => signRequest(),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

in the postman, I generate my access key and secret key then it works nicely.

[postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQrcE.jpg)

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? Can you please let us know what you did to fix the issue?

Comment: Anyway to send me this example but for POST instead of GET?

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at your code

```
$access_key         = 'my-access-key';
$secretKey          = 'my-secret-key';
```

You have to enter your values for access key and secret key there. I assume Amazon provided them for you?

Because your error message says

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

Comment: thanks @alexio for the response, I have access_key and secretkey but I'm sorry I can't show it. If I use rest api like postman it's work nicely. I hope you can show me what's wrong with my code. Thank you..

Comment: I was just suggesting to enter your code API keys there and thought maybe you haven't done it yet? Because the error message implies that.

Comment: No, you don't have to show it to me. Please remove it again. I think you misunderstood me. However, do you get another message now?

Comment: Okay @alexio, I got same message error, it always get The request signature error but I try in postman it works. I'm very confused.. do you have an idea ?

Comment: Can you show some code of postman? Where did you get the PHP code? From the Amazon docs?

Comment: I get the PHP code from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822768/signature-version-4-signing-process-in-php-to-access-api-gateway-endpoint?rq=1. the postman result is in my main post @alexio, please have a look.