# How to generate AWS SP-API signature using PHP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-selling-partner-api

When I use POSTMAN to obtain data from Amazon SP-API, it always returns proper results. However, I'm having some issues with AWS signature generation in PHP code.

I've followed the instructions in [AWS DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4 signing.html) but it always returns the following error.

`SignatureDoesNotMatch The computed request signature does not match the signature you gave. Examine your AWS Secret Access Key and signature technique. Details can be found in the service documentation.`

There is no issue with credential mismatch because all of the credentials are accurate. I believe there is a problem with HASH. I'm using the "SHA256" hash technique.

Can someone assist me in determining the correct reference of the AWS SP-API signature creation?

Thank you in advance.

```
------------------------- 1: Create a Canonical Request for Signature ----------------------------

echo $query_string = 'Action=AssumeRole&Version=2011-06-15&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=' . urlencode($access_key . '/' . $sDate . '/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request') . '&X-Amz-Date=' . $sTime . '&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=' . urlencode('content-type;host;x-amz-date');


$canonicalrequest = "";
$canonicalrequest .= "GET" . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "/" . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= $query_string . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "host:sts.amazonaws.com" . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "x-amz-date:" . $sTime . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= "content-type;host;x-amz-date" . "\n";
$canonicalrequest .= strtolower(bin2hex(hash('sha256', '', true)));


------------------------- 2: Create a String to Sign for Signature ------------------------------

$Algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
$RequestDateTime = $sTime;
$CredentialScope = $sDate . '/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request';
$HashedCanonicalRequest = strtolower(bin2hex(hash('sha256', $canonicalrequest, true)));
$StringToSign = $Algorithm . "\n" . $RequestDateTime . "\n" . $CredentialScope . "\n" . $HashedCanonicalRequest;


-------------------------------- 3: Calculate the AWS Signature -----------------------------------

$kSecret = "AWS4" . $secret_access_key;
$kDate = hash_hmac('sha256', $sDate, $kSecret, true);
$kRegion = hash_hmac('sha256', 'us-east-1', $kDate, true);
$kService = hash_hmac('sha256', 'sts', $kRegion, true);
$kSigning = hash_hmac('sha256', 'aws4_request', $kService, true);

$notHexSignature = hash_hmac('sha256', $StringToSign, $kSigning, true);
$signature = strtolower(bin2hex($notHexSignature));

-------------------------- 4: Add the AWS Signature to the Request --------------------------------

$session_token_url = 'https://sts.amazonaws.com?Version=2011-06-15&Action=AssumeRole&RoleSessionName=SessionToken&RoleArn=' . $role_ARN;
echo $session_token_url;

$session_token_header = ['X-Amz-Date: ' . $sTime, 'Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=' . $access_key . '/' . $sDate . '/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=' . $signature];

$session_token = api_call_for_session_token($session_token_url, 'GET', '', $session_token_header);


function api_call_for_session_token(string $url, string $method = 'GET', $body = null, $header)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $rescode = (int) curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $succesRescode = [100, 200, 201, 202, 205, 301];
    if ($err || !in_array($rescode, $succesRescode)) {
        $res = ['status' => false, 'message' => 'api call failed ' . $err, 'rescode' => $rescode, 'data' => json_decode($response, true)];
    } else {
        $res = ['status' => true, 'message' => 'api call success', 'rescode' => $rescode, 'data' => json_decode($response, true)];
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Hi buddy.. did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Following code sample working for me. Please make necessary credential change and execute get-order function to see if that works for you.

```
$long_date = gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z');
$short_date = substr($long_date, 0, 8);
$config = [
    'marketplace_id' => 'ATVPDKIKX0DER',
    'refresh_token' => 'YOUR-REFRESH-TOEN',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'host' => 'sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com',
    'client_id' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-ID',
    'client_secret' => 'YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET',
    'secret_key' => 'YOUR-SECRET-KEY',
    'role_arn' => 'YOUR-ROLE-ARN'
];
```

1. print_r(getAssumeRole($config));
2. print_r(getSign($config));
3. print_r(createFulfillmentOrder($config));
4. print_r(getFulfillmentOrder($config));

**//Operation: Get AssumeRole session token**

**//Description: Returns a set of temporary security credentials that you can use to access AWS resources. These temporary credentials consist of an access key ID, a secret access key, and a security token.**

```
function getAssumeRole($request) {
    $request['service'] = 'sts';
    $request['method'] = 'GET';
    $request['uri'] = '/';
    $request['host'] = 'sts.amazonaws.com';
    $request['query_string'] = ['Action' => 'AssumeRole', 'DurationSeconds' => 3600, 'RoleArn' => $request['role_arn'], 'RoleSessionName' => 'session1', 'Version' => '2011-06-15'];
    $request['headers'] = ['host' => $request['host']];
    $sign_data = getSign($request);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $sign_data['url'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $sign_data['headers'],
    ));
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    $session_token = $access_key_id = $secret_access_key = '';
    if ($code == 200) {
        $data = (array) simplexml_load_string($resp);
        $result = (array) $data['AssumeRoleResult'];
        $Credentials = (array) $result['Credentials'];
        $SessionToken = (array) $Credentials['SessionToken'];
        $session_token = $SessionToken[0];
        $AccessKeyId = (array) $Credentials['AccessKeyId'];
        $access_key_id = $AccessKeyId[0];
        $SecretAccessKey = (array) $Credentials['SecretAccessKey'];
        $secret_access_key = $SecretAccessKey[0];
    }
    return ['code' => $code, 'response' => $resp, 'access_key_id' => $access_key_id, 'secret_access_key' => $secret_access_key, 'session_token' => $session_token];
}
```

**//Operation: Create and sign your AWS request**

**//Description: You sign requests using your AWS access keys, which consists of an access key ID and a secret access key**

```
function getSign($request) {
    $method = isset($request['method']) ? $request['method'] : '';
    $canonical_uri = isset($request['uri']) ? $request['uri'] : '/';
    $secret_key = $request['secret_key'];
    $access_key = $request['access_key'];
    $region = $request['region'];
    $service = $request['service'];
    $host = $request['host'];
    $alg = 'sha256';
    $short_date = $request['short_date'];
    $long_date = $request['long_date'];
    $query_string = isset($request['query_string']) ? $request['query_string'] : [];
    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
    $payload = isset($request['payload']) ? $request['payload'] : [];
    $data = "";
    if ($service == 'execute-api' && is_array($payload)) {
        ksort($payload);
        $data = empty($payload) ? "" : json_encode($payload);
    }
    //prepare canonical query string
    $qa = [];
    ksort($query_string);
    foreach ($query_string as $k => $v) {
        $qa[] = $k . '=' . urlencode($v);
    }
    $canonical_querystring = !empty($qa) ? implode("&", $qa) : "";
    if ($service == 'execute-api') {
        $sts_data = getAssumeRole($request);
        $access_key = $sts_data['access_key_id'];
        $secret_key = $sts_data['secret_access_key'];
    }
    // Create signing key
    $kDate = hash_hmac($alg, $short_date, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
    $kRegion = hash_hmac($alg, $region, $kDate, true);
    $kService = hash_hmac($alg, $service, $kRegion, true);
    $kSigning = hash_hmac($alg, 'aws4_request', $kService, true);

    // Create canonical headers
    $cha = $sha = $headers = [];
    foreach ($request['headers'] as $k => $v) {
        $sha[] = $k;
        $cha[] = $k . ':' . $v;
        $headers[] = $k . ': ' . $v;
    }
    if ($service == 'execute-api') {
        $tr = json_decode(token($request));
        $x_amz_access_token = 'x-amz-access-token';
        $headers[] = $x_amz_access_token . ': ' . $tr->access_token;
        $sha[] = $x_amz_access_token;
        $cha[] = $x_amz_access_token . ':' . $tr->access_token;
    }

    $x_amz_date = 'x-amz-date';
    $headers[] = $x_amz_date . ': ' . $request['long_date'];
    $sha[] = $x_amz_date;
    $cha[] = $x_amz_date . ':' . $request['long_date'];

    if ($service == 'execute-api') {

        $x_amz_security_token = 'x-amz-security-token';
        $headers[] = $x_amz_security_token . ': ' . $sts_data['session_token'];
        $sha[] = $x_amz_security_token;
        $cha[] = $x_amz_security_token . ':' . $sts_data['session_token'];
    }
    $signed_headers = implode(";", $sha);
    $canonical_headers = implode("\n", $cha);
    // Create request payload
    $hashedPayload = hash($alg, $data);
    // Create canonical request
    $cr = array();
    $cr[] = $method;
    $cr[] = $canonical_uri;
    $cr[] = $canonical_querystring;
    $cr[] = $canonical_headers . "\n";
    $cr[] = $signed_headers;
    $cr[] = $hashedPayload;
    $requestCanonicalRequest = implode("\n", $cr);
    $canonical_request = hash($alg, utf8_encode($requestCanonicalRequest));
    $url = 'https://' . $host . $canonical_uri;
    $url .= !empty($canonical_querystring) ? '?' . $canonical_querystring : '';

    // Create scope
    $cs = array();
    $cs[] = $short_date;
    $cs[] = $region;
    $cs[] = $service;
    $cs[] = 'aws4_request';
    $credential_scope = implode('/', $cs);
    // Create string to signing
    $s2s = array();
    $s2s[] = $algorithm;
    $s2s[] = $long_date;
    $s2s[] = $credential_scope;
    $s2s[] = $canonical_request;
    $string_to_sign = implode("\n", $s2s);
    // Create signature
    $signature = hash_hmac($alg, $string_to_sign, $kSigning);
    // Create authorization header
    $ah = array();
    $ah[] = 'Credential=' . $access_key . '/' . $credential_scope;
    $ah[] = 'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers;
    $ah[] = 'Signature=' . trim($signature);
    $auth_header = $algorithm . ' ' . implode(', ', $ah);
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: ' . $auth_header;
    return ['headers' => $headers, 'url' => $url, 'requestCanonicalRequest' => $requestCanonicalRequest];
}
```

**//Operation: createFulfillmentOrder**

**//Description: Requests that Amazon ship items from the seller's inventory in Amazon's fulfillment network to a destination address.**

```
function createFulfillmentOrder($request) {
    $request['service'] = 'execute-api';
    $request['method'] = 'POST';
    $request['uri'] = '/fba/outbound/2020-07-01/fulfillmentOrders';
    $request['query_string'] = [];
    $sellerOrderId = 'PEER-TEST-' . time();
    $body = [
        'destinationAddress' => ['name' => 'Ray', 'addressLine1' => 'YourAddress', 'city' => 'CTY', 'stateOrRegion' => 'OG', 'countryCode' => 'US', 'postalCode' => '000'],
        'displayableOrderComment' => 'HappyShopping',
        'displayableOrderDate' => gmdate('Ymd\THis\Z'),
        'displayableOrderId' => $sellerOrderId,
        'items' => [
            ['sellerSku' => '8XXX', 'quantity' => 1, 'sellerFulfillmentOrderItemId' => 'BXXX']
        ],
        'sellerFulfillmentOrderId' => $sellerOrderId,
        'shippingSpeedCategory' => 'Standard'
    ];
    $request['payload'] = $body;
    $request['headers'] = ['content-type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'host' => 'sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com', 'user-agent' => 'spapi_client'];
    $request['url'] = 'https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/fba/outbound/2020-07-01/fulfillmentOrders';
    $sign_data = getSign($request);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $request['url'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $sign_data['headers'],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($request['payload'])
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    return ['code' => $code, 'data' => $data];
}
```

**//Operation: getFulfillmentOrder**

**//Description: Returns the fulfillment order indicated by the specified order identifier**

```
function getFulfillmentOrder($request) {
    $request['service'] = 'execute-api';
    $request['method'] = 'GET';
    $request['uri'] = '/fba/outbound/2020-07-01/fulfillmentOrders/{YOUR-ORDER-ID}';
    $request['query_string'] = [];
    $request['payload'] = [];
    $request['headers'] = ['host' => $request['host'], 'user-agent' => 'spapi_client'];
    $request['url'] = 'https://' . $request['host'] . $request['uri'];
    $sign_data = getSign($request);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $sign_data['url'],
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $sign_data['headers'],
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return ['code' => 200, 'data' => $data];
}
```

**//Operation: token**

**//Description: Returns the session token for API authentication**

```
function token($config) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' . $config['refresh_token'] . '&client_id=' . $config['client_id'] . '&client_secret=' . $config['client_secret'] . '',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Host: api.amazon.com', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8']
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

If anyone looking to generate SP-API credentials, can refer to this youtube video: https://youtu.be/JIqh5O7hxKQ

Hope this will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Here is one more set of API request using postman. Follow below link to geenrate request body:
https://www.postman.com/restless-capsule-266764/workspace/amazon-spapi/documentation/14782630-1d5c3014-c058-4857-9ecb-185458f7930e

#HappyCoding