# How do I sign AWS API requests with PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, curl, signing

I am trying to sign an AWS API request and then use cURL.

The purpose is to submit a tracking number to API of the service provider, and use the response.

I am a complete noob to AWS API and cannot find my fault after numerous testing.

I have tried numerous ways but all leads to `{"message":"Forbidden"}`.

Here is my current script:

```
<?php

    $accessKeyId = "AKIA55D**********";   
    $secretAccessKey = "NQ0xcl**********";  
    $method ='GET';
    $uri = '/tracking/shipments';
    $secretKey = $secretAccessKey;
    $access_key = $accessKeyId;
    $region = 'af-south-1';
    $service = 'execute-api';
    $host = "https://api.shiplogic.com";
    $alg = 'sha256';
    $date = new DateTime('Africa/Johannesburg');
    $dd = $date->format( 'Ymd\THis\Z' );
    $amzdate2 = new DateTime( 'Africa/Johannesburg' );
    $amzdate2 = $amzdate2->format( 'Ymd' );
    $amzdate = $dd;
    $algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
    $canonical_uri = $uri;
    $canonical_querystring = '';
    $canonical_headers = "host:".$host."\n"."x-amz-date:".$amzdate."\n";
    $signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date';
    $canonical_request = "".$method."\n".$canonical_uri."\n".$canonical_querystring."\n".$canonical_headers."\n".$signed_headers;
    $credential_scope = $amzdate2 . '/' . $region . '/' . $service . '/' . 'aws4_request';
    $string_to_sign  = "".$algorithm."\n".$amzdate ."\n".$credential_scope."\n".hash('sha256', $canonical_request)."";
   //string_to_sign is the answer..hash('sha256', $canonical_request)//

    $kSecret = 'AWS4' . $secretKey;
    $kDate = hash_hmac( $alg, $amzdate2, $kSecret, true );
    $kRegion = hash_hmac( $alg, $region, $kDate, true );
    $kService = hash_hmac( $alg, $service, $kRegion, true );
    $kSigning = hash_hmac( $alg, 'aws4_request', $kService, true );     
    $signature = hash_hmac( $alg, $string_to_sign, $kSigning ); 
    $authorization_header = $algorithm . ' ' . 'Credential=' . $access_key . '/' . $credential_scope . ', ' .  'SignedHeaders=' . $signed_headers . ', ' . 'Signature=' . $signature;

    $headers = [
                'content-type'=>'application/json', 
                'x-amz-date'=>$amzdate, 
                'Authorization'=>$authorization_header];
 
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments?tracking_reference=M3RPH',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'X-Amz-Date: '.$amzdate.'',
'Authorization: ' . $authorization_header . ''
 ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

The response I receive is `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not use:  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php

Comment: Thanks @y.bs. Will the sdk create a signature for the API request? I am new to AWS

Comment: I was not able to make it work with the SDK

Comment: The SDK is by far the easiest way of doing this. If you can't get it working, ask for help with that; you really shouldn't be self-managing AWS payload signatures.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz. I couldn't figure out which class to use to include my AWS access key and secret key, and how does the SDK sign the API request. Do you perhaps have guidance in that regard? Like I said, I am new to AWS.. thanks again

Comment: @CharlesTester See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials.html for suppling the SDK with credentials; the SDK automatically signs any calls it makes. So, if you do `$s3 = new S3Client; $s3->getObject(...)`, the signing occurs automatically as part of that request.

Comment: @ceejayoz I should mention that I do no own the API I am trying to connect to. I am developing software to connect to a supplier's API. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @CharlesTester No it does not - use the SDK; I would advise deleting this question as, as others have pointed out, the SDK exists to abstracts out this extreme low level stuff that nobody likes to (or should be) handling.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary It's useful as a question as probably more people start using Curl and then find they need to sign AWS requests and rewrite their code to use the SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install [Amazon's PHP SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php) as already pointed out in the comments.

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

The documentation of the API you're trying to call has [1 PHP code sample and it uses that SDK](https://api-docs.shiplogic.com/). All you need to do is insert your credentials.

```
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

function sign(
    RequestInterface $request,
    string $accessKeyId,
    string $secretAccessKey
): RequestInterface {
    $signature = new SignatureV4('execute-api', 'af-south-1');
    $credentials = new Credentials($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey);

    return $signature->signRequest($request, $credentials);
}
```

You can see both the input `$request` and the return value are of the same `RequestInterface`  type. So it gives you a modified request object with a proper signature (if your key and params are valid).

If you're using `curl`, you may not have this request object yet. Amazon's API uses the [PSR-7 standard request interface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/), most frameworks implement this if they have a request object.

If you don't have a request object at hand, you could use [Guzzle's implementation](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7) for it. The required packages are already installed as [dependencies of Amazon's SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/8f8742caa42b260950320c98ddc5da4926e2373d/composer.json#L20-L21). You can install both highlighted packages from the Github permalink.

```
 $request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request(
     'GET',
     'https://api.shiplogic.com/tracking/shipments',
     [
         // Maybe you still need headers.
     ]
 );
 $signed_request = sign($request);

 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $response = $client->send($signed_request);
```

As mentioned in the comments creating your own implementation of security components should be avoided as much as possible. It's a lot easier to rewrite your code to use this request object, especially for future maintenance.

Also keep in mind that your credentials might simply be invalid, or have no access to the resource you're requesting. At first sight most of your implementation seemed to follow what's expected from the [signing protocol](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html) (*though you just need 1 tiny mistake and it won't work*), so if you're sure you checked everything it might be as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks. Using `$request = new GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request...` I got an error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sign() `

Comment: The snippet uses the `sign` function of the previous snippet.

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request'` any ideas? I've done `composer require guzzlehttp/psr7` and `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: @inwerpsel thank you for such a neat little example. I think you should invoice Amazon for writing the missing part of their docs for them.